# Httpd management loadbalancer: (35) SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length

Tags: apache, ssl, httpd.conf

Trying to hit following url :

```
 conf.d]$ curl https://10.0.1.1:1002/status/modcluster -v
* About to connect() to 10.0.1.1 port 1002 (#0)
*   Trying 10.0.1.1...
* Connected to 10.0.1.1 (10.0.1.1) port 1002 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* NSS error -12263 (SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG)
* SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
```

following are httpd settings:

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.1.1:1002>
  ServerName loadbalancer01.qa.bntagrator.cosng.net

  # Keycloak security
  OIDCCryptoPassphrase a-random-secret-used-by-apache-oidc-and-balancer
  OIDCProviderMetadataURL https://auth.qa.bntagrator.cosng.net/auth/realms/bntagrator/.well-known/openid-configuration
  OIDCClientID apache-vhost-loadbalancer
  OIDCClientSecret b3eb9339-49fc-4d43-af32-07f70617044b
  OIDCRemoteUserClaim preferred_username
  OIDCRedirectURI https://loadbalancer01.qa.bntagrator.cosng.net/status/redirect-uri
  OIDCScope "openid"
  <Location /status>
    AuthType openid-connect
    Require valid-user
</Location>


# Mod Cluster status page
<Location /status/modcluster>
    AuthType openid-connect
    Require claim client_roles:view_modcluster_status
    SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
</Location>

# Default Apache httpd status page
<Location /status/server>
    AuthType openid-connect
    Require claim client_roles:view_loadbalancer_status
    SetHandler server-status
</Location>
```

What modifications required in this file to make it work?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to access a site by HTTPS which is  configured for plain HTTP only. The plain HTTP response of the server will be blindly interpreted as HTTPS (TLS) which typically causes all kinds of strange errors, like claims of wrong protocol version, record too long or similar. *"What modifications required in this file to make it work?"* -  properly enable HTTPS which includes use of certificates. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html

Comment: Just to add on Steffen comment. Where is your SSLEngine directive and the directives loading key and cert?